# Ebay PuslarIO questions

Tags: java

I am investigating ebay's pulsarIO in order to do event processing.
https://github.com/pulsarIO/realtime-analytics/wiki/PulsarIO-Demo

I can't understad some stuff and hope someone here can help:

1. What are subsessions and why they have their own TTL?
2. What catches the TTL and start processing?
3. When events are persisted?  at the end of the stream or when the entire session is finished?
4. They add events to session using a queue -> In cluster, How can you handle race conditions and insure true events order in session?

Help please

Regards, 
Id

Comment: Did you read all resources in the wiki @ github? Did you read https://github.com/pulsarIO/realtime-analytics/wiki/documents/Whitepaper_Pulsar_Real-timeAnalyticsatScale.pdf?